# Jmeter Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have an issue when using Jmeter BeanShell preprocessor.
The script invoke jars which I have put them under directory "D:\Software\apache-jmeter-3.0\lib\ext".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMNt7.png)

here is my BeanShell code:

```
import com.evergrande.api.test.JsonClientUtil;
import com.evergrande.common.utils.JsonUtil;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

JsonClientUtil jcu=new JsonClientUtil();
ObjectNode node = JsonUtil.createObjectNode();//when I try to use the method in JsonUtil(Class)，it came out error
```

Error:

```
2016/09/24 22:48:06 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import com.evergrande.api.test.JsonClientUtil; import com.evergrande.common.util . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation JsonUtil.createObjectNode 
2016/09/24 22:48:06 WARN  - jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval    Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import com.evergrande.api.test.JsonClientUtil; import com.evergrande.common.util . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation JsonUtil.createObjectNode
```

I can invoke "createObjectNode" method in my java Code.
So,how can I fix this issue? Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't put any jars to the `lib/ext` folder, it should be used for JMeter core components and plugins only. Put your .jar libraries to "lib" folder of somewhere else, they just need to be on the [JMeter's Claspath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath). Alternative option is using `Add directory or jar to classpath` option on [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) level

   [image: extra jars to classpath]
2. JMeter restart is required to pick the jars up.
3. You can get more readable Beanshell error message by surrounding your code with [try/catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) block like

   ```
   import com.evergrande.api.test.JsonClientUtil;
   import com.evergrande.common.utils.JsonUtil;
   import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

   try {
       JsonClientUtil jcu=new JsonClientUtil();
       ObjectNode node = JsonUtil.createObjectNode();
   }
   catch (Throwable ex) {
       log.error("Beanshell failure: ", ex);
       throw ex;
   }
   ```

   So if your script fails you will be able to see stacktrace details in the *jmeter.log* file. Another approach of getting to the bottom of your Beanshell script failure is adding [debug();](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#debug) command to the beginning of your script. It will trigger verbose output to the console. Check out [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more information on JMeter debugging techniques.

Comment: Thank you! I have solved this problem. It's because of lack of Jar package.